# Python, How to efficiently make a nested dictionary from a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that looks like this

```
[['ip1',404],
['ip1',200],
['ip1',200],
['ip2',200],
['ip2',200],
['ip2',504]]
```

I need to make a dictionary that has counts of the status codes by ip address.

```
results = {'ip1':{404:1,200:2},'ip2':{200:2,504:1}}
```

Comment: When providing sample code, please at least check that it's syntactically valid.

Comment: I fixed it, http://sscce.org/#co

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tools in collections make short work of this problem:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> d = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for ip, code in [['ip1',404], ['ip1',200], ['ip1',200],
                     ['ip2',200], ['ip2',200], ['ip2',504]]:
        d[ip][code] += 1

>>> dict(d)
{'ip2': Counter({200: 2, 504: 1}), 'ip1': Counter({200: 2, 404: 1})}
```

Comment: This is now part of my toolkit...never knew it was there!

Comment: It is not necessary to convert result to `dict` - `defaultdict`/`Counter` are the subclasses from `dict` and can be used directly.

Comment: @astynax I'm pretty sure this is just done for viewing purposes.

Comment: `Counter` is cool - not seen that before.  New in python 2.7 though: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood For people using older Pythons, there is a Py2.5 backport at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> ips = [['ip1',404],['ip1',200],['ip1',200],['ip2',200],['ip2',200],['ip2',504]]
>>> for ip,num in ips:
        d[ip][num] += 1

>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00000000035D6648>, {'ip2': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {200: 2, 504: 1}), 'ip1': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {200: 2, 404: 1})})
```

Comment: That answer works but a *Counter* inside the *defaultdict* is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
values =   [['ip1',404],
            ['ip1',200],
            ['ip1',200],
            ['ip2',200],
            ['ip2',200],
            ['ip2',504]]

counts = {}

for value in values:
    ip, status_code = value
    if ip not in counts:
        counts[ip] = {}
    if status_code not in counts[ip]:
        counts[ip][status_code] = 0
    counts[ip][status_code] += 1

{'ip2': {200: 2, 504: 1}, 'ip1': {200: 2, 404: 1}}
```

it should work on virtually any python version.

Comment: +1 for backwards compatibility.  `dict.setdefault` would shorten the code and has been around so long that when it was introduced is not mentioned in the docs! http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault Eg `for ip, status_code in values: counts[ip][status_code] = counts.setdefault(ip,{}).setdefault(status_code, 0) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l
[['ip1', 404],
 ['ip1', 200],
 ['ip1', 200],
 ['ip2', 200],
 ['ip2', 200],
 ['ip2', 504]]

>>> {ip: {code: l.count([ip, code])
...    for code in (p[1] for p in l if p[0]==ip)}
...          for ip in (p[0] for p in l)}
{'ip1': {200: 2, 404: 1}, 'ip2': {200: 2, 504: 1}}
```

Comment: This is not very efficient in the computational sense, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [[ip1,404], [ip1,200], [ip1,200], [ip2,200], [ip2,200], [ip2,504]]
D = {}

for entry in L:
    ip = entry[0]
    code = entry[1]
    ip_entry = D.get(ip, {})
    ip_entry[code] = ip_entry.get(code, 0) + 1
    D[ip] = ip_entry
```